# StAX splitting large items file with shared tags

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

Using java StAX, starting with `big.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <attribute>g3</attribute>
    <multi>
        <attribute>g1</attribute>
        <attribute>g2</attribute>
    </multi>
    <item>
        <attribute>l13</attribute>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>l11</attribute>
            <attribute>l12</attribute>
        </attributes>
    </item>
    <item>
        <attribute>l23</attribute>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>l21</attribute>
            <attribute>l22</attribute>
        </attributes>
    </item>
    <item>
        <attribute>l33</attribute>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>l31</attribute>
            <attribute>l32</attribute>
        </attributes>
    </item>
</items>
```

I'm spliting this into `small_1.xml` and `small_2.xml` and `small_3.xml`

where every small file has all global attributes beside corresponding item's local attributes.

Example: `small_1.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <attribute>g3</attribute>
    <multi>
        <attribute>g1</attribute>
        <attribute>g2</attribute>
    </multi>
    <item>
        <attribute>l13</attribute>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>l11</attribute>
            <attribute>l12</attribute>
        </attributes>
    </item>
</items>
```

---

With this java src

```
        try {
        String itemTag = "item";
        String itemsTag = "items";
        int itemID = 0;

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = null;

        xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("big.xml"));

        XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamWriter xsw = null;

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();

        t.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes"); //not working

        while (xsr.hasNext()) {
            if (xsr.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT) {
            } else if (xsr.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
                if (xsr.getLocalName().equals(itemsTag)) {
                } else if (xsr.getLocalName().equals(itemTag)) {
                    xsw = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileWriter(new File("small_" + ++itemID + ".xml")));
                    t.transform(new StAXSource(xsr), new StAXResult(xsw));
                    xsw.close();
                }
            } else if (xsr.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT) {
            } else if (xsr.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT) {
            } else {
            }
            xsr.next();
        }

    } catch (

    Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the output `small_1.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<item>
    <attribute>l33</attribute>
    <attributes>
        <attribute>l31</attribute>
        <attribute>l32</attribute>
    </attributes>
</item>
```

**I've 2 questions:**

1. How to capture global sub-tags of `<items>` tag to be added to every small file:

   ```
   <attribute>g3</attribute>
   <multi>
       <attribute>g1</attribute>
       <attribute>g2</attribute>
   </multi>
   ```
2. when trying to add multiple items per file, I ended up with multiple XML declarations `<?xml version="1.0"?>`.

I tried

```
    t.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes");
```

but it isn't working!